# .IndexOf function returns a negative in vb.net for a List of class

Tags: vb.net, list, class, object

I've been having no end of trouble using a list of a class structure - I've been trying to make a dictionary in console. Every element in the list has four properties: the .Word, the .Definition, the .Example, and an .IsDefined boolean property. The class looks like this:

```
Class Term
    Public Word As String
    Public Definition As String
    Public Example As String
    Public IsDefined As Boolean
End Class
```

The sub I'm trying to write is supposed to change a value in the list, by finding the index of the given value, then it asks the user to input new data, and then it's supposed to change the object. Only it fails here:

```
IndexPosition = TerminologyDictionary.IndexOf(Term1)
```

TerminologyDictionary is a List(Of Term), and Term1 is the term object the user has asked to be edited. There's only one element in TerminologyDictionary, and all four properties of it are exactly the same as Term1. I've even checked using QuickWatch, the statements...

```
TerminologyDictionary(0).Word = Term1.Word
TerminologyDictionary(0).Definition = Term1.Definition
TerminologyDictionary(0).Example = Term1.Example
TerminologyDictionary(0).IsDefined = Term1.IsDefined
```

...all evaluate to True, whether I use the Is operator or the equals. But when I test TerminologyDictionary(0) Is Term1, it returns false.

I've got around this by using my own function to go through the list and test every property against each other manually and return an index when they all come out to true, but it's messy, and I'm wondering if there's something simple I've done wrong, or if there's some way to do it using .IndexOf. I know that there's .FindIndex, but I don't understand the whole Predicate thing, .IndexOf is a lot simpler.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

By default `IndexOf` compares by reference only since your custom class has not overridden `Equals`. When you override `Equals` you should always also override `GetHashCode`.

So this should work:

```
Class Term
    Public Word As String
    Public Definition As String
    Public Example As String
    Public IsDefined As Boolean

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Dim t2 = TryCast(obj, Term)
        If t2 Is Nothing Then Return False

        Return Word = t2.Word AndAlso
            Definition = t2.Definition AndAlso
            Example = t2.Example AndAlso
            IsDefined = t2.IsDefined
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Dim hash As Integer = 23
        hash *= 17 + Word.GetHashCode()
        hash *= 17 + Definition.GetHashCode()
        hash *= 17 + Example.GetHashCode()
        hash *= 17 + IsDefined.GetHashCode()

        Return hash
    End Function
End Class
```

**Edit**: Maybe this implementation of `GetHashCode` is better since VB.NET lacks [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a569z7k8.aspx):

```
Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    Return New With {Word, Definition, Example, IsDefined}.GetHashCode()
End Function
```

It's less efficent since every `GetHashCode` call needs to create an instance of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

The `IndexOf` method uses the standard comparison for the type in the list, and for reference types the standard comparison compares the references to the objects, not the values in the properties in the object.

You can use the `FindIndex` method like this:

```
IndexPosition = TerminologyDictionary.FindIndex(Function(term As Term) _
  Term1.Word = term.Word and _
  Term1.Definition = term.Definition and _
  Term1.Example = term.Example and _
  Term1.IsDefined = term.IsDefined _
)
```